# Hide group of columns with values ​0 or null - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, hide, group

How to hide a group of columns with values ​​0 or null (service 1 and service 3) ?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart : {type: 'column'},
    xAxis: { categories: ["service 1", "service 2", "service 3", "service 4"] },
    series: [
       { name: 'person1',
         data: [0,2,null,6],
       },
       { name : 'person2',
         data: [0,6,null,5]
       }
    ]
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mg7yz2r6/1/

[image]

I need the graph to look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to preprocess your data and remove such values before the chart is created. For example:

```
const categories = [...];
const series = [...];

const indexesToRemove = [];

series[0].data.forEach((dataEl, index) => {
    if (series.every(s => !s.data[index])) {
        indexesToRemove.push(index);
    }
});

while (indexesToRemove.length) {
    const index = indexesToRemove.pop();
    categories.splice(index, 1);
    series.forEach(s => {
        s.data.splice(index, 1);
    });
}


Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories
    },
    series
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fqt0rwpz/

---

If it is not possible, you can dynamically add x-axis breaks in places of empty categories.

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks